# inner.HTML not centering inside if functions

Tags: javascript, html

Code Sample:

```
var msg = document.getElementById("message");

//constructor
function person(name,birthMonth,profession){
//set default values to a person
this.name = name || "No Name";
this.birthMonth = birthMonth || "No Month";
this.profession = profession || "Nobody";

    //construction of the display function
    this.display=function (){
        msg.innerHTML += "<center><p>" + this.name + " " + "was born on " + this.birthMonth + " and they are a " + this.profession + ". "

                //Month comparisons
                if (this.birthMonth=="April"){
                    msg.innerHTML += "They are meh because they were born in April.(eww)"
                }
                else if (this.birthMonth=="January"){
                    msg.innerHTML += "They are the best because they were born in the <strong>best month!</strong>"
                }
                else {
                    msg.innerHTML += "They are okay, at best."
                }
        //close paragraph tag       
        msg.innerHTML += "<hr></p></center>"
    }

}
```

Question: Why isn't the msg.innerHTML inside of the if/else statements centered? Shouldn't the center tags catch them? In the HTML output, the first statements before the if/else is centered. Also, the hr prints correctly, so I am confident is it outputting that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Because [`<center>` doesn't work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) Check out [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) instead.

Comment: Interesting because the first line is centered. I prefer text-align myself, was just toying with innerHTML.

Comment: @MikeC just because it's depreciated doesn't mean it isn't supported; I can still center elements in Chrome 53 with it.

Comment: @Polyov True. I suppose I ought to have said you should treat it as unsupported. hairmots answer is spot on for the actual problem.

Comment: Right, but "deprecated" means "can go away at any time", so it is dangerous to use-- better to stick to supported API elements.

Answer (score 3):

The browser is automatically closing the center tag when the first innerHTML is called.

Build up a string variable with the full message, then set the innerHTML at the end - as you close the center tag, the browser will not need to do anything and your text will render as you require.

```
this.display=function (){
var mess = '';
    mess += "<center><p>" + this.name + " " + "was born on " + this.birthMonth + " and they are a " + this.profession + ". "

            //Month comparisons
            if (this.birthMonth=="April"){
               mess += "They are meh because they were born in April.(eww)"
            }
            else if (this.birthMonth=="January"){
                mess += "They are the best because they were born in the <strong>best month!</strong>"
            }
            else {
                mess += "They are okay, at best."
            }
    //close paragraph tag     
    mess += "<hr></p></center>"
    msg.innerHTML = mess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The  tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."
Use `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: But that's not what's causing the issue. Despite `<center>`'s depreciation, it's still supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Using document fragments and CSS provide faster responses

```js
var msg = document.getElementById("message");

//constructor
function person(name, birthMonth, profession) {
    //set default values to a person
    this.name = name || "No Name";
    this.birthMonth = birthMonth || "No Month";
    this.profession = profession || "Nobody";

    //construction of the display function
    this.display = function() {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var para = frag.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
        para.className = "message";
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.name + " " + "was born on " + this.birthMonth + " and they are a " + this.profession + ". "));

    //Month comparisons
    if (this.birthMonth == "April") {
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("They are meh because they were born in April. (eww)"));
    } else if (this.birthMonth == "January") {
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("They are the best because they were born in the best month! "));
        var strong = para.appendChild(document.createElement("strong"));
            strong.textContent = "best month!";
    } else {
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("They are okay, at best."));
    }

    msg.appendChild(frag);
    };

}

var test1 = new person("Bob", "April", "Developer");
    test1.display();
var test2 = new person("Bobby", "January", "Developer");
    test2.display();
var test3 = new person("Rob", "else", "Developer");
    test3.display();
```

```css
.message {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```